# Youtube video playing correctly on Windows but not on Linux server

Tags: css, linux, html

I am a beginner in HTML.
My school gave us a project where to build a simple website. While adding a YouTube video to the code, it works perfectly and plays on any Windows browser but not on any Linux servers as my teacher said. What should I do?

Here's the video code:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videocode"
width= "760" height="240"  allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: *"I removed <> on iframe because it wouldn't show up in the post"* - If you format your code as code, then it should render properly.

Comment: Which distro are the Linux servers running (Red Hat, Ubuntu, etc.)? What browser are you using on the Linux servers. What makes them "servers"?